# 3d Table to 2d table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have generated a Table in 3 dimensions, for two variables `x`, `y`.

```
grid = {{{1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}}, {{1, 0}, {1, 
   1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}}, {{2, 0}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 
   3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{3, 0}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}, {3, 
   5}}, {{4, 0}, {4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}}}
```

and I have computed values for each point using `Map[myFunction[#[[1]], #[[2]]] &, grid, {2}]`, which has given me

```
myOutput = {{-3.8627*10^-23, 0.000246833, 3.08541*10^-8, 2.57117*10^-12, 
  1.60698*10^-16, 8.03492*10^-21}, {0., -3.8627*10^-23, 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {-1.8303*10^-26, 0., 0., 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}
```

I have the grid in Dimensions `{5,6,2}` and my values in Dimensions `{5,6}`. I would like to have a plain but readable table that has one one axis one dimension of the `grid`, on the other the other dimension, and the table cells containing the function values. Basically a `ListPlot3d`, but not as a plot, but with numbers. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Isn't `MatrixPlot[ ]` or `ArrayPlot[ ]` what you're after?

Comment: Or even `Grid[ ]`

Comment: @belisarius `MatrixPlot` and `Grid` both are almost there, but I can't find a way to add the grid (the coordinates from `grid`) to the picture.

Comment: Well you don't really have a grid: some coordinates are missing (e.g., (0,0)), and others are duplicated. (e.g., (1,1)).

Comment: @Alan my calculations are not valid on the `(0,0)` point, so that was my quick-and-dirty solution to that. If this is an issue, feel free to replace the first `(1,1)` with `(0,0)` again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grid = Flatten[grid, 1]
myOutput = Flatten[myOutput, 1]
stubs = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Map[First, grid]]
headers = Sort@DeleteDuplicates[Map[#[[2]] &, grid]]
MapThread[Rule, {grid, myOutput}]
Table[{i, j}, {i, stubs}, {j, headers}] /. % /. {_, _} -> Null
TableForm[%, TableHeadings -> {stubs, headers}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
TableForm[myOutput, TableHeadings -> {Range[0, i - 1], Range[0, j - 1]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]